# Array Empty after pushing axios response and other data : Node.Js

Tags: node.js, promise, axios

I have an array,That contain some records with image.I'm trying to do is,convert image url in to base64 and assign new records into new Array.but i'm getting empty array.

```
  var newArray = [];

    devices.map(async (data) => {

     const imgData = await axios.get(data.image[0], { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
     let returnedB64 = Buffer.from(imgData.data).toString('base64')
     newArray.push([data.identifier, data.model, data.imei,
               data.locationText, returnedB64])

    })

 console.log("Final array --->", newArray)  //i'm getting empty
```

Comment: Last `console.log` statement will execute _before_ async code executes and returns the required data.

Comment: @Yousaf yes thats what i want to resolve

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

You don't `await` for the response, so your array is empty when `console.log` gets executed. the correct approach is:

```
Promise.all(devices.map(async (data) => {
     const imgData = await axios.get(data.image[0], { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
     const returnedB64 = Buffer.from(imgData.data).toString('base64');
     return [data.identifier, data.model, data.imei, data.locationText, returnedB64];
})).then(allResults => {
     console.log("Final array --->", allResults);
});
```